# Getting rendered Screen as (feedback-) Texture (Shadtertoy)

Tags: glsl, shader

Is it possible to access a rendered image (GLSL) in the next frame with shader toy?

Answer (score 1):

Now they have implemented rendering to buffers, so you can render to buffer. Actually, you can use up to four buffers, if you need. Also, watch useful [demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtsSW8).

Answer (score -1):

No. There is no access to previously rendered frames.