# How can i get previous frame data in glsl?

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

There is a site, [shadertoy.com](http://www.shadertoy.com) where i can easily test glsl code. Now I would like to play with my webcam. One my required step is to lowpass renderred image between frames:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    fragColor.rgb = prevColor.rgb*0.9 + texture(iChannel0, uv).rgb*0.1;
}
```

New webcam frame is located in `iChannel0` texture;  but `prevColor` - I can*t get. Where can I get previously rendered frame? Or how can I store rendered `fragColor.rgb` data, to make it "survive" between passes?

Comment: it is done on CPU side code.... see `glReadPixels` , `FBO` , rendering to texture etc ... the duplicate has no accepted answer but the answers there are correct you can not do this in shaders only. As you are grabbing the Webcam images so you can directly store them into texture (txr0 or txr1) and swap similarly like double buffering ...

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634861/getting-rendered-screen-as-feedback-texture-shadtertoy), also no accepted answer.

Ah okay, i've managed to find it out on my own. It is called "backbuffer", here is [demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtsSW8) i've found.

Here, [on stackoverflow were answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634861/getting-rendered-screen-as-feedback-texture-shadtertoy), now they are outdated;
Feature was implemented not so long ago. Now it is possible.